# How To Configure Nginx as a Web Server and Reverse Proxy for Apache on One Ubuntu 18.04 Server

Tags: nginx

I want to access my website through  Nginx as a Web Server.I just came accross an issue. Doesn't matter if its a local setup or one with a domain name.I want to setup my domain using Nginx server.

Any one can help to setup to my configuration. I am using aws ec2 server for hosting

Due to configuration unable to run my site.

Comment: please add the error you are receiving in your nginx logs.

Comment: I am testing using sudo nginx -t run successfull but when running sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-61-248: Resource temporarily unavailable